# Display None CSS Rule disabling JS code when removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

EDIT:
The mobile query class .Nav contains "display: none;" within it. The javascript code works as intended opening and closing the desired classes. Although the open class is invisible due to the "display:none" in the .Nav class. Once this code is removed, The javascript no longer works. You can view it on my website https://blacklist-rs.com/design/

```js
document.querySelector('#menu-icon').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.nav-container').classList.toggle('nav-open')
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#000;
    font-family: 'EurostileBold', sans-serif;
}

#background{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .header #menu-icon{
        left: 35px;
        top: 46px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-image:url(https://blacklist-rs.com/design/img/menu.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor:pointer;
    }   

    .nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:99999;
    display:none; /** Code that makes the javascript work **/
/** Once removed, menu displays but javascript doesnt work **/
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.nav-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-340px;
    width: -340px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
}

.nav-open {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:340px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(340px,0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(340px,0);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header">    
                <div id="menu-icon"></div>  
                <div class="nav">
                <div class="nav-bg-close"></div> 
                <div class="nav-container">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="main-menu">
                    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul></div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can create a [mre]. It is probably becasue you did not set initial position/visibility for the `.nav-container`. Consider using left: -340px` instead of `translateY (-340px)`. I it still doesn't work, create a jQuery function that close the `nav-container` on page load.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i remove the visibility: hidden css rule, The javascript no longer works.
I've done what you have suggested, It works the same as my code.
Within the Media Query for mobile, Visibility: hidden is the reason it does not show the menu. Once that rule is removed, The javascript does not work.

Comment: For some reason your provided code doesn't work on my native environment too

Comment: Yeah, That's the issue I'm facing. I know it doesn't work, but just displaying the code that is required. If you view this in inspect element, you'll see the container opens through highlighting the class on inspect element but its invisible.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, The JavaScript doesn't trigger anything now. And adding the background-color to .nav does still show the colour.

Comment: I've actually removed the .nav css inside the media query as it's not needed. The JS isn't triggering anything though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that JS will work as long as these two elements exist: `#menu-icon` and `.nav-container`

I've tried removing .nav css inside media query, the JS toggles class `nav-open` and shows the menu.

```js
document.querySelector('#menu-icon').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.nav-container').classList.toggle('nav-open')
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#000;
    font-family: 'EurostileBold', sans-serif;
}

#background{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .header #menu-icon{
        left: 35px;
        top: 46px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-image:url(https://blacklist-rs.com/design/img/menu.svg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor:pointer;
    }   
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.nav-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:-340px;
    width: -340px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
}

.nav-open {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:340px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(340px,0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(340px,0);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header">    
                <div id="menu-icon"></div>  
                <div class="nav">
                <div class="nav-bg-close"></div> 
                <div class="nav-container">
                    <div class="close"></div>
                    <div class="main-menu">
                    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul></div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Brilliant, Unfortunately this doesn't work with mine. I'll upload the corrected version & you can inspect element on them. https://blacklist-rs.com/design/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I didn't move `<div id="menu-icon"></div>` inside `<div class='nav'>`. I only removed `.nav` css inside media query

Comment: Yeah, I updated it and doesn't work locally or on my website.. I have additional CSS in the media query & the navigation are on separate style pages.

Comment: Have you updated it to your site? Because what I see here: menu-icon is still inside **nav** div?

Comment: I've just checked the site. Do you also need `nav-bg-close`? If you remove it, it will trigger toggle, but right now that div is covering the icon so it's not clicked.

Comment: Yeah it's updated, It's probably cache that is not making it updated.
I intend on using nav-bg-close to close the menu without having to click the X icon

Comment: Everything works perfect, Added another function to close it using the #close id.

Next objective is to create an off-screen tap to close the menu. Appreciate all the help! Thank you!